# open to deep link from local notification when app is inactive

Tags: swift, uilocalnotification, deep-linking

I want to schedule local notification for X minutes and take user to a specified link when actioned.

currently when the app is in `foreground` or `inactive` the delegate method `UNUserNotificationCenter(didReceive: withCompletionHandler:)` is called and the app works as expected (the deep link opens)

the issue I'm running into is when the notification is received when the app is suspended or background and the notification launches the application I cannot seem to capture where the link is received and cannot follow the link, from what I can see that delegate method is not called?

below is the implementation for `UNUserNotificationCenter(didReceive: withCompletionHandler:)`

```
defer {
    completionHandler()
}

guard
    response.actionIdentifier == UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier ||
    response.actionIdentifier == "open-dl" else {
    return
}

guard
    let url = response.notification.request.content.userInfo["link-to"] as? String,
    let linkTo = URL(string: url) else {
    return
}

if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .background {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(linkTo, forKey: "localdeeplink")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
} else {
    _ = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.application?(UIApplication.shared, open: linkTo, options: [:])
}
```

When I attempt to read that `localdeeplink` entry back out of `UserDefaults` it's empty.

Comment: when you are having this issue is `UNUserNotificationCenter(didReceive: withCompletionHandler:)` getting called?

Comment: when I go from suspended, background -> receive notification -> tap on notification -- I do not know for sure if the function is called, I am assuming it is not called because the Userdefaults entry is not set.

Comment: this function is getting called? print some thing to know, i assume it is not getting called

Comment: I can't print anything because to test I need to kill the app and receive the notification, the debugger is not attached

Comment: You can upvote and accept the answer if it does help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    //add this function
    if launchOptions != nil {
        pushAction(launchOptions: launchOptions)
    }
    return true
}

func pushAction(launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) {
    //add code of UNUserNotificationCenter(didReceive: withCompletionHandler:) here
}
```

Add the code of `UNUserNotificationCenter(didReceive: withCompletionHandler:)` in `pushAction` function

When app is closed `didRecive` is not getting called, `didFinish` is called with the push payload.

[Apple link](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/HandlingRemoteNotifications.html) go to `Handling Remote Notifications` at bottom

Comment: ok so, how do I pull the local notification out of the launch options?
the key to do it is deprecated?